# Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets when using Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following code fails on one file, at the arrow. The new file is created, but it fails to copy values. The same code works on a separate file, in exactly the same form. The code has not been touched in years, and it worked fine 4 weeks ago when last used, so it seems a bug on Google's part or something changed server side.

```
function copySheetValuesAndFormat(sourceName, destination, startData){
  
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sourceName)
  var sValues = source.getDataRange().getValues();
  source.copyTo(destination).setName(sourceName)
  var destinationSheet = destination.getSheetByName(sourceName)
  ---> destinationSheet.getRange(1,1,sValues.length,sValues[0].length).setValues(sValues)
  checkRange = destinationSheet.getRange('D1:D')
  lastRowWithData = getLastRowWithDataInARange(checkRange, startData)
  lastRow = destinationSheet.getMaxRows()
  destinationSheet.deleteRows(lastRowWithData + 1, lastRow - lastRowWithData - 1)
  

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Google side bugs should be reporte on th issue tracker. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#bugs

Comment: Please provide an example that produces the error.  It's called a [mcve]

Comment: I'd guess one of  your inputs has got a problem like perhaps one of the the destinations is not a spreadsheet.  Use the debugger to single step through the program checking all of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

#### Address comments in code

```
function copySheetValuesAndFormat(sourceName, destination, startData){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sourceName);
  var vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  sh.copyTo(destination).setName(sourceName);//this should work if destination is in fact a range not just an A1 notation
  var destinationSheet = destination.getSheetByName(sourceName)
  destinationSheet.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs)
  checkRange = destinationSheet.getRange('D1:D')//this is a bad way to assign a range
  //try this instead destinationSheet.getRange('D1:D' ( destinationSheet.getLastRow()))
  let lr = destinationSheet.getLastRow()
  destinationSheet.deleteRows(lr + 1, destinationSheet.getMaxRows() - lr + 1);//not sure about this
}
```